# Change the visibility of textbox in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have developed a layout which has 2 textboxes and 1 button. At the first, the button is appear and two textboxes are disappeared. However, I dont know how can I change the visibility of textboxes and other components to appear when the insert button is pressed. Please explain simply because I am new in android.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Main3Activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Address"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextAddress"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insert"
        android:onClick="insert"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main2Activity

```
package com.example.alan.mainactivity;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Main2Activity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public static final String USER_NAME1 = "USERNAME";

    String myJSON;
    private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextAdd;
    private static final String TAG_RESULTS="result";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_ADD ="address";

    JSONArray peoples = null;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> personList;

    ListView list;



    Button btn_insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Similarly the other views.....
        }
    });



    public void insert(View view){

        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();

        insertToDatabase(name, add);
    }

    private void insertToDatabase(String name, String add){
        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String paramUsername = params[0];
                String paramAddress = params[1];


                String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String add = editTextAdd.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME).toString();

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", add));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", username));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://www.oobac.com/app/insert-db.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                return "success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
                textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, add);
    }
    //-----------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
       TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

       textView.setText("Welcome " + username);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }



    protected void showList(){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);

                HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

                persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
                persons.put(TAG_NAME,name);
                persons.put(TAG_ADD,address);

                personList.add(persons);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    Main2Activity.this, personList, R.layout.list_item,
                    new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_NAME,TAG_ADD},
                    new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.address}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void getData(){
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                //--------------------------------------------
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.oobac.com/app/amir.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Log.d("TK SUPPORT", "In the try Loop" + st);
                    myJSON = st;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TK SUPPORT", "Connection Error : " + e.toString());
                }
                return "OK";



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                showList();
            }



        }

        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Comment: set onclicklistener on button and in onClick method set textview visibility gone or visible as you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SAMPLE SNIPPET

    replace your onCreate method to this method
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME);
        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
       TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
 Button btn_insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //Similarly the other views.....
        }
    });
       textView.setText("Welcome " + username);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }
```

Comment: Error:(56, 5) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(56, 29) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(56, 30) error: ';' expected
Error:(58, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:(60, 6) error: illegal start of type
Error:(58, 35) error: ';' expected

Comment: have you find your textView ?

Comment: I have copied and pasted you code to my MainActivity

Comment: I have updated the question by java code. Please see it yourself Tnx

Comment: Error:(129, 28) error: cannot find symbol class Button
Error:(129, 9) error: cannot find symbol class Button

Comment: Add this 
import android.widget.Button;

Comment: Thank you it is working however the public void insert(View view){ does not work anymore :(

Comment: remove this line from xml
android:onClick="insert"
and call insert function manually from onClick method

Comment: I have removed onClick="insert" from xml file and add insert(); manually to onClick which you write. It gives me error

Comment: Error:(145, 17) error: method insert in class Main2Activity cannot be applied to given types;
required: View
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104968/discussion-between-khizar-hayat-and-mohammad-ali-nematollahi).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class variable like this

```
private TextView yourTextView;
```

You should get the instance of your TextView like this

```
yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_editText);
```

Then on button click, setVisibility to visible

```
Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.m_button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            yourTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
});
```

To hide, setVisibility to Gone

```
yourTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Error:(63, 13) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(66, 31) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(66, 32) error: illegal start of type
Error:(66, 35) error: ')' expected
Error:(66, 40) error: ';' expected
Error:(66, 41) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(68, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:(68, 35) error: ';' expected
Error:(71, 6) error: illegal start of type
Error:(73, 27) error: ';' expected
Error:(73, 35) error: ';' expected
Error:(75, 31) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(75, 41) error: <identifier> expected

Answer (score 0):

Use the setVisibility property to hide your views.

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

View.GONE This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

Also

```
yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

View.INVISIBLE This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn_insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

          TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
          textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         //Similarly the other views.....
            }
        });
```

Comment: Error:(60, 34) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(60, 35) error: illegal start of type
Error:(60, 38) error: ')' expected
Error:(60, 43) error: ';' expected
Error:(60, 44) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(62, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:(62, 35) error: ';' expected
Error:(69, 6) error: illegal start of type
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi get the ids of every view component.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, You are setting `android:onClick="insert"` in layout xml and you are also setting click listener in `onCreate` method too. So either remove from xml or onCreate listener.  **Secondly**, in `onClick`, TextView textView=

```
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for respond. You mean I cannot have a button to show two textboxes as well as add?

Comment: No, you can have as many number of TextViews as you want. The problem is, when you press the button, onClick is called. You are setting two listeners for the same button. one `onClick` in layout xml and second in oncreate using btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 0):

In Simple way Just put your onClicklistener() of button inside onCreate() method like this ..

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String username = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME);
            editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            editTextAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAddress);
           TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

 Button btn_insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn_insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //do it here whatever u want to do on press of button 
                //Similarly the other views.....
            }
        });

           textView.setText("Welcome " + username);

            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            getData();


        }
```